# Salesforce Debug Levels - Need to edit or delete existing level

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

Can we manage Debug levels in Salesforce?
Delete or Edit or at least Rename existing debug level?

I have created a new debug level but missed something and now would like to either change levels to what I need, delete it and create a new one, or rename it to JUNK_whatever and create a new one.
Neither of these options seems to be available. Maybe I simply didn't find it?

P.S. I don't currently have any user trace flags or debug logs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can edit and delete [DebugLevels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_debuglevel.htm).

From UI perhaps easiest is to use the Developer Console (upper right corner, gear/cog icon). Debug -> Change Log Levels -> Add/Change. Highlight (click) the row you want and remove. It's bit finnicky but it works.

[image].

You can do it from setup too but I think it shows up only in Classic interface. Switch and type "debug levels" or try `https://{my domain here}.my.salesforce.com/7dl`

[image]

Last but not least you could fire a Tooling API query on the table and then it's a HTTP DELETE request sent to `v55.0/tooling/composite/sobjects?ids=recordId`. You may need Postman, SoapUI or Workbench for that.

Comment: In dev console I had some random flags. I'm not even sure what that was about.
In Classic - Debug levels worked as expected and I was able to delete my erroneous entries. Thank you!